# PHP difference in ways of templating

Tags: php, html, templates

I'm trying to differ my site to different templates so it is easier to control.
Now Im using simple `include 'tpl/something.inc'` But i heard of something like template engine on PHP(Using ob_start()), so what the difference between them? Is it safe to do it my way?

Answer (score 1):

Though you provided very little info, I would not categorize that sort of templating system as unsafe. You can create very secure templating systems with that model. However, you can get a lot more features, security, and reliability if you use a premade templating system instead of one you make yourself. I would highly recommend using [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), which is free and open source. It is has a huge feature set & is highly extensible, both with community plugins or by creating functions yourself.